# Is numpy.linalg.cond returning the ratio of the biggest and smallest eigenvalue?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, eigenvalue

I need to calculate the ratio of the biggest and smallest eigenvalue of a matrix, which is called "condition number" as far as I know. I have found the `numpy.linalg.cond` that computes the condition number of a matrix, but I was wondering if this actually corresponds to the ratio between the biggest and smallest eigenvalues. Can someone give me indications on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation np.linalg.cond is defined as the norm of the array times the inverse of the norm of the array which is not what you are looking for. But what you want can easily be done:

```
    import numpy as np

    Eigs = np.linalg.eigvals(yourarrayhere)
    cond = np.max(Eigs)/np.min(Eigs)
```

Comment: Condition number is the ratio of largerst and smallest *singular values*, not the ratio of eigenvalues. For general matrices these are not the same thing. For so-called [normal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) singular values however are absolute values of eigenvalues.

Comment: I think some people have a different definition of condition number. For instance in Nonlinear Programming by Bertsekas, the second edition and third printing he specifically calls the ratio of the largest to the smallest eigenvalue the condition number on page 67. If the condition number is large he callse the matrix ill-conditioned

Comment: The standard linear algebra definition is the ratio of 2-norms as above, i.e. the ratio of singular values. This equals the ratio of eigenvalues only for (positive definite) normal matrices. What you write above is incorrect, since numpy.linalg.cond uses the standard definition.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misread your answer, the text as it stands is correct.